# Handle upscaling in Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot

Can anyone suggest me that if we want to do upscaling our application then how can we do that?

Upscaling in the sense that handling extra load by adding hardware/software resources at runtime, so how can we do that using Spring Boot?

Is there any way or functionality that we can apply?

Comment: you can setup load balancer between two or more instance of spring-boot app

Comment: Ok, thank you so much for your quick response, I will try it and let you know.

Comment: While set a load balancer between spring boot app instances, I need to manage the sessions between them, so how to do Session Management when we have a load balancer in case of Spring boot ?

Comment: Try to setup sticky load balancing

Comment: Thanks for your response, That can be the solution, but it is very old one approach, people are not using it now a days, do we have any other approach for it?